# How can I set a minimum password length when using the built-in Django auth module?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I’m implementing authentication in a Django site using [the built-in auth module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/), including [the built-in `UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms).

I’d like to set a minimum length for passwords. However, I can’t find any documentation on how to do this.

Can I configure the auth module’s `User` module to require this at the database level? Or should I sub-class the `UserCreationForm` (I’m actually doing this already for unrelated reasons) and add an extra validator that enforces the password length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Especially if you're already using a sub-classed `UserCreationForm`, I'd say you should definitely just add the validation to it. You should be able to override the `clean_password` method on the form:

```
def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    if len(password) < 8:
        raise ValidationError('Password too short')
    return super(MyUserCreationForm, self).clean_password1()
```

Comment: 2 questions:  1) Why use super() here?  Why not `return password`? 2) I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'clean_password'`.  What might cause that?

Comment: It should be `clean_password1` not `clean_password` (and `self.cleaned_data.get('password1')`) since UserCreationForm has a `password1` and `password2` for confirmation.

Comment: There is a better way. See other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39714008/3708462

Comment: What is the default minimum length if `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` not used? How can I check, is there a method?

Answer (score 45):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is using [Django password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#password-validation)

For minimum length would be enough adding this to settings file:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 8,
        }
    },
]
```

There are others validators like `NumericPasswordValidator` and `CommonPasswordValidator`

Comment: This is the better answer! Don't fiddle with clean methods if there is a password_validation mechanism built-in!

Comment: Works perfectly with Django 2+ and Wagtail 2+

Answer (score 4):

Subclassing the user creation form sounds like a good approach. You can't enforce it at the database level, since Django only stores a hash of the password.

Answer (score 1):

Some info about answers,

```
django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator
```

was newly implemented from [django 1.9+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) for older version it wont work,

so you can go with your own custom validator,

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

def validate(min_length, password):
    special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;'\[\]]"
    if len(password) < 8:
        raise ValidationError(ugettext('Password length must be greater than 8 character.'))
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
        raise ValidationError(ugettext('Password must contain at least %(min_length)d digit.') % {'min_length': min_length})
    if not any(char.isalpha() for char in password):
        raise ValidationError(ugettext('Password must contain at least %(min_length)d letter.') % {'min_length': min_length})
    if not any(char in special_characters for char in password):
        raise ValidationError(ugettext('Password must contain at least %(min_length)d special character.') % {'min_length': min_length})
```

Answer (score 0):

/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py Contains class MinimumLengthValidator with default the password minimum length:

```
class MinimumLengthValidator(object):
    """
    Validate whether the password is of a minimum length.
    """
    def __init__(self, min_length=8):
        self.min_length = min_length

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if len(password) < self.min_length:
            raise ValidationError(
                ungettext(
                    "This password is too short. It must contain at least %(min_length)d character.",
                    "This password is too short. It must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.",
                    self.min_length
                ),
                code='password_too_short',
                params={'min_length': self.min_length},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return ungettext(
            "Your password must contain at least %(min_length)d character.",
            "Your password must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.",
            self.min_length
        ) % {'min_length': self.min_length}
```