# Django 'super object has no attribute clean_password1()'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to subclass Django's default usercreation form, but it fails for some reason at this function:

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
    if len(password) < 8:
        raise ValidationError('Password too short')
    return super(UserRegistrationForm, self).clean_password1()
```

It throws an error I put in the title on the last line of this code. I tried clean_password, clean_password(), and clean_password1(), but nothing works. Django version is 1.6.2 What is wrong?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488078/how-can-i-set-a-minimum-password-length-when-using-the-built-in-django-auth-modu) question for advice.

Comment: What's the name of your class? Is it `UserRegistrationForm`, or is that the superclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [Django's code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.2/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L67) in GitHub, there's no method called `clean_password1` or `clean_password`. There's a method called `clean_password2` though :) Since there's no special check for the password, I suggest you just write

```
return password
```

**EDIT** Err, yes, there's a special check, the passwords must be identical. But this check will be done anyway wathever you call it or not.

Comment: Just a side remark about Django's code, why the "2" at the end of the method name ? That makes the method more unreadable.

Comment: Because there's two fields, `password1` and `password2` in the actual html and in the `UserCreationForm` code. Django automatically call the cleaning method for each field IF they are named clean_{field_name}. That's why they have this ugly name :) If you name your field `dirty_salad`, your method will be named `clean_dirty_salad`.

Comment: Yes, when I replaced it with return, everything went fine. Thank you, I should check the code more often :)